# Adding column to iReport crosstab (not a column group)

Tags: jasper-reports

So, lets take this simple source table as an example:

[image]

The crosstab I'm currently having looks like this:

[image]

The question is: how do I add a column after "Total" column, having some information about units (just a text field with a value depending on a unit name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is quite simple: divide "Total" column, adding separate Text Field with the desired expression.